# Chapter heading

Tags: formatting, chapters

I am using the `report` class with combinations of `fancychap` and `fancyhdr` packages. It always display a chapter title in capital letters, I want it to display a title as it is given to the `\chapter` command.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} 
\usepackage{float,lscape}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{High performance}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to throw

```
\ChNameAsIs
\ChTitleAsIs
```

into your preamble.

See also Section 2.1 (page 3) of the [fancychap documentation](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution. Use `\ChTitleAsIs` or `\ChNameAsIs` as you need

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} 
\ChTitleAsIs %\ChNameAsIs

\begin{document}
    \chapter{High performance}
\end{document}
```

[image]